# How to Rename Complete Xcode Project using command line?

Tags: xcode, command-line, rename

I am trying to rename my xcode project using command line but some how it's not renaming entire project. My project structure is bit more nested and I need to replace one string which is even a sub string of Project name and some files names I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824737/xcode-6-3-1-crashes-while-renaming-project/29830195#29830195,  but it's not worked for me with this project but for some other project(which is sample app with not much nested structure) it worked well. . Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: “trying to rename my xcode project using command line” Why not just rename it the normal way?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but normal renaming not works for my project structure, because of it's nested structure and by doing that I need to do lot of additional manualy work.

Comment: But surely you’re only going to do this once! Anyway you’ve said nothing specific about your “structure” or what you are really trying to do. Actually needing to rename a project is very rare.

Comment: My Project have four levels of nesting, in each level I have some files and sub folders, here in file content(code), file names,Folder names  have the Sub string I have to change. Some how I am able to change the code and outer folder names, only problem is renaming the filenames in each and every levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and nice solution for my question. By following this link I achieved what exactly I want , It saved my most of time, https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/32r8i6/findreplace_string_in_files_filenames_and/