# Error: Xcode does not support opening folders without a project or workspace

Tags: xcode

I was trying to duplicate a project using this process [Duplicate and rename Xcode project & associated folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744319/duplicate-and-rename-xcode-project-associated-folders)

It wasn't working for me, so I deleted the duplicate folder. I'm reasonably sure I didn't delete the original project, or change any of its files or filenames. Now when trying to open the original project, I get the error

"Xcode does not support opening folders without a project or workspace."

I don't know what triggers Xcode to recognize something as a project. Any idea what I did?

Edited to ask a more specific question:
How can I open this existing project, and then do whatever needs to be done to make it usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in Xcode 6.3, trying to rename a project causes a crash and leaves the project in an unusable state. That's a bug, of course, but it's not a very nice thing to do to the developer.

EDIT: Apple has just (secretly) released Xcode 6.3.2 GM seed, which is said to fix the crashing bug.

FURTHER EDIT: Xcode 6.3.2 final (not GM) really does appear to fix the crashing bug.

Comment: The workaround that I am currently using is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29745844/341994

Comment: Oh man, that is a serious bummer. The directions you link to say that I should open the project and then delete/recreate the Scheme, but I can't open the project - it just gives me the above error message. Can you clarify? 

I'm new to both xcode and StackOverflow - not sure if more appropriate to ask for clarification here or on the question you linked to.

Comment: Right but first you have to add the extension, as those directions tell you. The extension got stripped during the crash.

Comment: There is no file missing an extension in my folders. There is no "appname.xcodeproj" or "appname"

Comment: Well, in that case you have no project file at all and you'll just have to give up - there's no project to open. Are you sure you don't see a folder called "appname" (or whatever it is) inside the project folder?

Comment: There is a folder, but also no project file inside that folder. Here's the contents of the first folder http://screencast.com/t/lT5ReyqY and then when you open the YarnLabelMinder (that's the app name) folder there's this http://screencast.com/t/hzGZKAKFI But no missing extension names, or project files. Unless I'm misunderstanding and the *folder* itself is supposed to have that extension.

Comment: I think the project file was completely destroyed. However, you do have all your other files, so just create a whole new project and import things one by one...

Comment: Well that's a bummer. This is my very first project in XCode, and I'm not sure how to import files one by one. Maybe I should start a separate thread for that?

Comment: Just make a new project. Drag a code file or a storyboard file from the old project folder (in the Finder) into the new project (in Xcode) and accept the options to copy it and to make it part of the target.