# Not able to run once renaming is done in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode6.3

I renamed a project in Xcode 6.3 and I found the Active Schema in the tool bar has changed to settings kind of Icon and I can't run the project in simulator as well as in device.

[image: Here my target device is iPad, but I can't find the iPad in the list]

How can I get rid of this. Please clarify..

Comment: You should almost never rename a project. It will haunt you :p. Your scheme is probably configured incorrectly because it hasn't reflected your new project name.

Comment: How can I configure the schema back?? @Schemetrical

Comment: [Try this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHr1vjkTxC0)

Comment: I have just created a new scheme with the same target solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in xcode 6.3 which leads to unexpected behaviour when you rename a project.

Read the following post to rename your project in case you dont have a backup.
[Xcode 6.3 is crashing on Project Rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692487/xcode-6-3-is-crashing-on-project-rename)